# How do you convince development teams to move to a new version of middleware?

Tags: project-management, software, software-updates

I'm working on a project to update our (out of support) middleware stack to a stable but supported version.  There are several teams with applications running on the version we currently have in production and understandably nobody wants to carry the risk of being the first to run on the newer version.

What strategies have you used or found most compelling to move to a new release like this in the past?

There are some performance and functional benefits offered by the newer version but there isn't really any major technical incentive for the teams to move that's a must-have right now.  This is mainly being driven by the cost of extended support for the old version and also a desire by the infrastructure teams to be running on a supported version with the improved management offered by the newer version.

It's more of a people question than a technology question.

Answer (score 4):

Deprecated or obsolete products or frameworks are usually best categorized (and "sold") as [Technical Debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

If the new version offers fantastic improvements or benefits, then your job is easier. But even if it doesn't, staying on an older version incurs several risks:

- Lack of developer support. This is never a problem until it's a problem - get it?
- Lack of community support. Over time, the forums, Q&A sites, mailing lists, etc. that you've come to rely on will start ignoring your questions because nobody uses your version anymore.
- Rev-lock. Upgrades become progressively more painful the more versions you are behind. Upgrading from 1.0 to 1.1 or from 1.9 to 2.0 is usually no big deal, but upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0 might take weeks or months to sort out all the issues. Paradoxically for managers, the *more frequently* you upgrade, the *less overall time* you will spend on upgrades, because the scope of changes is small for each, and problems are easy to fix.
- Loss of productivity (AKA opportunity cost). "Some" performance and functional benefits may not seem very interesting, but that 10% boost is compounded over every feature/sprint/release and amortized over a period of several weeks or months. If you could complete an estimated 12-month project in 10 months by spending 1 week on the upgrade, wouldn't that be a wise investment?
- Legacy code problems. Once a new version has fairly wide distribution, the developer will usually stop fixing bugs, security vulnerabilities, and other serious problems on the older versions. This significantly increases your chance of encountering a critical failure or a system being compromised or your data being stolen. Zero-day vulnerabilities exist but their exploitation is nowhere near as common as those from old, unpatched systems.

This doesn't mean that you always need to be on the latest and greatest version of *everything*, as there are problems associated with that as well. But on my team I make a point of upgrading at least *one* framework to the latest version at the beginning of every sprint. If it causes problems, fix them or roll it back. It's not a difficult pace to maintain, and it means we're *usually* no more than a month or two behind on any single product or framework, except sometimes where IT or corporate needs to be involved.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** There are quite different approaches on how you convince the software developers and/or the project managers to introduce something new or upgrade application.

Thus, software developers are interested in **saving time**, and useful features while doing some common and challenging tasks with different flavor, and PMs are interested in **saving costs** of the ongoing operations by proposed new/upgrade implementation.

Only main and important dis-advantage comes forward from QA team members, when the current application testing is not automated by scripts. The QA team may naturally oppose this changes.

There are related SE questions on `How to convince` your work place to make some changes with arguments:

- [How to Convince management to upgrade to .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5635169/1437962)
- [How to convince a colleague that code duplication is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226284/1437962)
- [How to convince management that QA is important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432512/1437962)
- [How to convince people to comment their code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159597/1437962)

Comment: _"software developers are interested in saving time"_ -- in my experience, it was quite often an opposite, when things involved learning new tech / skills that could be "good for resume", ie bring better opportunities at job market. Also...

Comment: ... _"interested in saving costs"_ -- this hasn't always been the case in my experience. Eg, in one of the past projects I've seen enormous, mad costs spent on bringing particular key customer on board. This "investment" eventually paid of by getting us about 10 more customers, but this happened much later

Comment: Yes, that is true, answer attempts to address it in statement - **saving time**, and useful features while doing some common and challenging tasks with different flavor